# How to get top most parent of a subcategory in joomla?

Tags: joomla

Is there any function of joomla that gives the top most parent of a subcategory?
Like, I have this structure-

[image]

If I have id of "`Components`" than how could I get "`Sample Data-Articles`".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getPathRoot and select the second to last node (the last node is the category root which itself is not a category).
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/table/nested.php#L126
or
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/categories/categories.php#L932